# Resize Android tablet app to android phone

Tags: android, layout

Im creating an app and im testing on a android tablet. Which means im using dimensions and positioning to fit the tablet screen. However as this app will be available for both tablet and phone im wondering is there a way of auto scaling for any device??

Thanks

[image]

Im using map fragment, rss feeds contained in listview and i have buttons.

im wondering if its complicated to scale down for a android phone?? or is it simple enough.
Im currently testing on a tablet running 4.0.4 but app is compatible with newer and older android versions.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/tableLayout1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@color/white">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="413dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button5"
        class="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment" />



    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_width="305dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="34dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:onClick="ClickTourismButton"
        android:layout_below="@+id/map"
        android:text="Touism Guide" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/button5"
        android:layout_width="34dp"
        android:textIsSelectable="true"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/grey"
        />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/button6"
        android:layout_width="34dp"
        android:textIsSelectable="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true" 
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/grey"
        />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button4"
        android:layout_width="305dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
       android:layout_marginLeft="34dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button3"
        android:text="Whats Nearby" />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="305dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="34dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button4"
        android:text="Favouites" />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="304dp"
       android:layout_marginLeft="34dp"  
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button2"
        android:text="See Full Map" />   

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="260dp"
        android:layout_height="413dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:textIsSelectable="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/map"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/button6"
        android:id="@+id/feedupdate1" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:background="@color/red"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/map"
        android:layout_width="260dp"
         android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_height="413dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/empty"
        android:textIsSelectable="true"
        android:layout_width="260dp"
        android:layout_height="413dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
         android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/feedupdate"
        android:layout_width="260dp"
        android:layout_height="390dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="6dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="430dp"
        android:textIsSelectable="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button3"
         />
    <ListView

        android:id="@+id/list1"
        android:background="@color/blue"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_width="260dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="430dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="6dp"
        android:layout_height="390dp" /> 




</RelativeLayout>
```

---

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/LinearLayout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:background="@color/white">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        class="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
         />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_weight=".10"
        android:layout_marginLeft="34dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:onClick="ClickTourismButton"
        android:label="@string/Tourism" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button4"
        android:layout_weight=".10"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="34dp"
        android:label="@string/Nearby" />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_weight=".25"
        android:layout_marginLeft="34dp"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:label="@string/Favourites" />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_weight=".25"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="34dp"  
        android:label="@string/Map" />

    </LinearLayout>   


    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
    <TextView

        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:textIsSelectable="true"      
        android:id="@+id/feedupdate1" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:background="@color/red"
        android:layout_weight="1"       
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/empty"
        android:textIsSelectable="true"   
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"  
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
         android:layout_marginTop="5dp"/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/feedupdate"        
        android:layout_marginLeft="6dp"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="430dp"
        android:textIsSelectable="true"/>
    <ListView

        android:id="@+id/list1"
        android:background="@color/blue"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="430dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="6dp" /> 

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: your image was not been seeing here

Comment: The subject is extensively described [here](http://developer.android.com/design/style/devices-displays.html).

Comment: Add to bump up my 'reptutation'. The app main screen is what you see. Im curious as to layout scaling? ive heard all you need is compatibility library or something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is better to use `layout weight` and `weightsum` property of the view wherever possible. It'll ensure that your views take up only that percentage of the screen space that you wish to specify. Thus, it'll scale your views for viewing in small or big screens.

Comment: Ive added my layout.xml file above. Should i get rid of width and height and just use layout weight and weightsum??

Comment: Unless you want to use fill_parent and wrap_content (which would look terrible on different screens sizes), I suggest you to define weights for each view. Using definite values for these will limit your views to a certain width or height but using weights will expand or collapse your views according to screen sizes.

Comment: Ok, How would i go about using weights to recreate the exact location of the black rectangle fragment in my layout? i assume its still ok to use android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button5"

Comment: Keeping margins is okay. Use linear layouts instead of relative layout which does not have the weight property. As I can see, you can use two vertical linear layouts for both the left and right views you have. Then, you can provide weightsum to the linear layout and give weights to each view in your linear layout as you like.

Comment: Its not working. First linear layout overlaps second?? new code is posted above

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you will have a problem as long as you are making use of `fill_parent`, `wrap_content` wherever possible. still do search "Android Compatibility Package" on developers.android.com

You will get a handful of info on that link.

Comment: I use individual widths and heights for each component

Comment: For different devices this may become a problem. for it to work on all devices you would have to use "wrap_content" or "fill_parent" which is more general in my opinion.